# Why I am not able to console.log(props)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-props, console.log

When I am trying to console.log(props) it is giving me an empty object.
It returns as {}.
And also in console when I try to write props it gives
VM410:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: props is not defined
at :1:1
Although it is defined in code
Here is the code

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { getProductsBySlug } from '../../actions';
import { Layout } from '../../components/Layout'

/**
* @author
* @function ProductListPage
**/

export const ProductListPage = (props) => {
  const dispatch=useDispatch();
  console.log(props);
  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log(props);
    dispatch(getProductsBySlug());
  },[]);

  return(
    <Layout>
      ProductListPage
    </Layout>
   )

 }
```

This is the product.action.js file from which I am getting Product List Page

```
import axios from "../helpers/axios";

export const getProductsBySlug=(slug)=>{
    return async dispatch=>{
        const res=await axios.get(`/products/${slug}`);
        console.log(res);
    }
}
```

This is the Layout Page

```
import React from 'react'
import { Header } from '../Header'
import { MenuHeader } from '../MenuHeader'

/**
* @author
* @function Layout
**/

export const Layout = (props) => {
  return(
    <>
        <Header/>
        <MenuHeader/>
        {props.children}
    </>
   )
   

 }
```

This is the header file

```
import React from 'react'
import './style.css';
/**
* @author
* @function Header
**/

export const Header = (props) => {
  return(
    <div className='header'></div>
   )

 }
```

This is the menuheader file

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import './style.css';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { getAllCategory } from '../../actions';

/**
* @author
* @function MenuHeader
**/

export const MenuHeader = (props) => {

  const category = useSelector(state => state.category);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getAllCategory());
  }, []);


  const renderCategories = (categories) => {
    let myCategories = [];
    for (let category of categories) {
      myCategories.push(
        <li key={category.name}>
          {
            category.parentId ? <a
              href={`/${category.slug}?cid=${category._id}&type=${category.type}`}>
              {category.name}
            </a> :
            <span>{category.name}</span>
          }
          {category.children.length > 0 ? (<ul>{renderCategories(category.children)}</ul>) : null}
        </li>
      );
    }
    return myCategories;
  }
  return (
    <div className="menuHeader">
      <ul>
        {category.categories.length > 0 ? renderCategories(category.categories) : null}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )

}
```

Basically the reason I am logging out prop because when I am going through the link http://localhost:3000/Samsung and i want to send the get request to Samsung but it is actually going to undefined http://localhost:2000/api/products/undefined

So how can I get the Samsung in place of undefined.

Comment: "When I am trying to console.log(props) it is giving me an empty object" — Do you have some reason to think it shouldn't be an empty object? We can't tell. Your code is missing any sign of you using `ProductListPage`; you haven't provided a [mcve].

Comment: "And also in console when I try to write props it gives VM410:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: props is not defined at :1:1 Although it is defined in code" — It's not a global. Did you put a break point inside the component and reach it before trying to access it with the console?

Comment: Why props should not be empty? From your code don't see any reason, why it shouldn't be empty

Comment: The video I  am referring to it is giving history match and location as it's key in it's output with which I will be able to pass proper slug in the ProductListPage function but here i am not able to get anything.

Comment: Probably they have their component nested inside a React Router provider. Anyway this is horribly constructed question. I would suggest you edit it to provide more details.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> When I am trying to console.log(props) it is giving me an empty object. It returns as {}.

This happens if you do not pass any props to the element.
i.e doing this:
`<ProductListPage />`

Instead of this: `<ProductListPage testProp="123 />`

> And also in console when I try to write props it gives VM410:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: props is not defined at :1:1 Although it is defined in code

Props object is local to your function component. The one you try to call in the browser console is not defined in the global scope.

[Read more about javascript scope](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Bro Just use useLocation() from react-router-dom.

import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const location = useLocation();
const slug = location.pathname.split("/")[1];